# Convert a bytea into a binary string

Tags: postgresql, binary-data, bytea

I need to decode a base64 string and take a chunk of binary.

Is there a SQL function in Postgres to simply convert a `bytea` into a binary string representation?
(Like *"00010001010101010"*.)

Answer (score 12):

If your Postgres installation runs with the default setting [`bytea_output = 'hex'`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT), there is a very simple hack:

```
SELECT right(bytea_col::text, -1)::varbit;
```

Example:

```
SELECT right((bytea '\xDEADBEEF')::text, -1)::varbit;
```

Result:

```
'11011110101011011011111011101111'
```

`right(text, -1)` is just the cheapest way to remove the leading backslash from the text representation.

[`varbit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html) (standard SQL name [`bit varying`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html)) is for bit strings of arbitrary length. Cast the result to `text` or `varchar` if you like.

Related, with explanation:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)

Answer (score 3):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=487b213c9fb06a9728b3b351dec88bea)

You could put the following code into a function:

```
WITH byte AS (   -- 1
    SELECT E'\\xDEADBEEF'::bytea as value
)
SELECT
    string_agg(      -- 5
        get_byte(value, gs)::bit(8)::text -- 4
        , ''
    )
FROM 
    byte,
    generate_series(        -- 3
        0, 
        length(value) - 1   -- 2
    ) gs
```

I demonstrated the development of the query within the fiddle.

1. The `WITH` clause encapsulates the `bytea` value for double usage in further code
2. `length()` calculates the binary length of the `bytea` value
3. `generate_series()` creates a list from `0` to `length - 1` (`0 - 3` in my example)
4. `get_byte()` takes the `bytea` value a second time and gives out the byte at position `gs` (the previous calculated values `0-3`). This gives an `integer` representation of the the byte. After that the cast to `bit(8)` type converts the result of this function to its binary representation (1 byte = 8 bit)
5. `string_agg()` finally aggregates all for binary strings into one. (taking its `text` representations instead of `bit` type, with no delimiters)

---

A function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION to_bit(value bytea) RETURNS SETOF text AS 
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
        SELECT
            string_agg(get_byte(value, gs)::bit(8)::text, '')
        FROM 
            generate_series(0, length(value) - 1) gs;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

After that you could call it:

```
SELECT to_bit(E'\\xDEADBEEF'::bytea)
```

---

You could try it using `get_bit()` instead of `get_byte()`. This safes you the `::bit(8)` cast but of course you need to multiply the length with factor `8` indeed.

The resulting bit string has another bit order but maybe it fits your use case better:

```
WITH byte AS (
    SELECT E'\\xDEADBEEF'::bytea as value
)
SELECT
    string_agg(get_bit(value, gs)::text, '')
FROM 
    byte,
    generate_series(0, length(value) * 8 - 1) gs
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=588a0679b6cd45cd4447e1d3f8f88844)